# Confusion regarding Related Employment Assessment

Tags: australia, skilled-migration

I have recently been invited to apply for the Australian Skilled Independent Visa (subclass 189) visa.  However, I would like clarification on this item: I claimed 5 points with my 1-year work experience here in Australia, which is related to my field. Do I need skill assessment for the 1-year experience in Australia?

Comment: You're quite welcome; that's what we're here to do; no need to thank.

Answer (score 1):

From the [guidelines](https://www.acs.org.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/7319/Skills-Assessment-Guidelines-for-Applicants.pdf), yes, all claimed work experience needs to be assessed.

There can be extra points awarded if you have an Australian degree with 1 year or more post-graduation work experience.

Comment: Thank you very much Dorothy, I do really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused a bit SkillSelect usually read directly from agency that assessed your skills (in my case ACS) and then get you the points...

With report from SkillSelect you then make application to get the Visa...

[image]

In example above you can see how points are being assigned (by the ASC by references that you had to provide to get the points in the first place), once you get your points from SkillSelect only then you apply for visa, or am I missing something?